# Как создать свой шаблон для dotnet core

Tags: .net-core

В интернете есть несколько примеров создания своих шаблонов для .Net Core. При этом все они представляют из себя выжимку из документов json и xml и обычно не собираются. Кроме этого, на сайте Microsoft есть статья, в которой говорится о невозможности сборки шаблонов из под ОС, отличной от Windows
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скриншот был сделан с веб страницы https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/tools/custom-templates 14 января 2018 года в 23:37.

Так кому же верить? Дайте инструкцию и пример шаблона, который полностью готов к сборке

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример готового к сборке шаблона для .Net Core можно получить из этого github репозитория:
https://github.com/tripolskypetr/AvaloniaUiAppTemplate

Древо файлов представленно на скриншоте
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На самом верхнем уровне находится файл .nuspec и директория Content. В файле nuspec находится описание пакета именно для nuget, на шаблон оно никак не отражается. Его содержимое представленно ниже

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2011/08/nuspec.xsd">
<metadata>
<id>avaloniaui.app</id>
<version>2.0.0</version>
<title>avaloniaui.app</title>
<authors>AvaloniaUI</authors>
<projectUrl>https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia</projectUrl>
<requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
<licenseUrl>https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT</licenseUrl>
<description>"dotnet new" template to create app with AvaloniaUI.
</description>
<copyright>AvaloniaUI</copyright>
<tags>dotnet new AvaloniaUI gui template</tags>
<packageTypes>
<packageType name="Template" />
</packageTypes>
</metadata>
<files>
<file src="AvaloniaUI\**"/>
</files>
</package>
```

Тут самое главное - тег files. Стоит запомнить, что путь указывается в стиле Windows и следует использовать *, чтобы всё содержимое папки AvaloniaUI из этого примера было добавлено в пакет

Внутри директории AvaloniaUI находится папка Content, внутри которой следует СРАЗУ поместить исходники. Нет, не папку с исходниками, а именно исходники. Это важно

На одном уровне с исходниками создаем директорию .template.config и кладем в нее файл template.json Именно этот файл будет содержать информацию для .Net Core

```
{
"author": "AvaloniaUI",
"classifications": [".Net Core", "dotnet", "template", "gui","avalonia"], 
"name": "AvaloniaUI GUI app",
"identity": "Core.AvaloniaUI.Template", 
"shortName": "avaloniaui",
"tags": {
    "language": "C#"
},
"sourceName": "AvaloniaAppTemplate"
}
```

Именем шаблона соответственно является содержимое shortName, а именно - avaloniaui

Так же СТОИТ ЗАМЕТИТЬ, что сочетание букв, хранящееся в sourceName (а именно AvaloniaAppTemplate) будет заменено на имя текущей директории при создании проекта из шаблона. Это относится к пространству имен и названию файла проекта .csproj

На момент написания пакета успешно собирает. Тестировал на Windows
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ссылка на скачивание примера в самом верху ответа